# Creating Table with variable name in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Trying to automate a job and have a dynamic table name with the following format:

`sales_yyyymm` where `yyyymm` is last month's date.

Has anyone done it?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to send a `CREATE TABLE` command and have Redshift 'calculate' the table name? No, this is not possible. However, you could probably do it within a [Stored Procedure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-create.html).

Comment: I want to have a command that says create table sales_yyyymm where yyyymm is worked out using current_date

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in SQL in Redshift AFAIK.  When I've needed to have automation of this kind it is the job of the external to Redshift automation tool to provide the table names if they are variable.  Redshift runs the SQL, the external tool generates the SQL.

A word of warning - Redshift is very good with big tables and does ok with small tables.  The process you are laying out has the possibility to make many very small tables and want to treat them as if they are a big table.  There are a number of issues that can crop up if you do this (assuming you are).  Since the minimum storage size on Redshift (block) is 1MB and that these are multiplied out over columns and slices - a table of a few thousand rows can take up a lot of space.  This affects disk storage, disk IO, and overall complexity of the query plan.  If you plan on making 10,000 tables of 10,000 rows each I promise you are going to have a bad time.